# Apache Karaf Runs Slower on Intel Board

Tags: linux, karaf

We are working on a IoT project, where we deployed our bundles first on a windows machine followed by a linux machine. This works fine. Now we are using Intel Socx1000 board (embedded). We have deployed the same bundles along with Karaf in that embedded board. I am seeing slowness in terms of start up and reponse. In normal linux machine the start up takes hardly 10 secs, and response time is around 1 to 2 secs. Where as in the embedded board its taking around 20 mints for start up and response time is around 50 secs.We are using around 29 bundles. Does anybody have idea as what can be done here?Do we need to manipulate some of the configurations that brings the embedded board back to normal. Pls help.

Thanks,
RK

Answer (score 0):

On a board like that, Karaf is always going to heavyweight.

Consider using pax-runner instead:

https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/paxrunner/Pax+Runner

This will allow you to use Felix (and therefore the OSGi core of Karaf), and precisely control which bundles are actually loaded.